# How to display random avatar for each user which comes from an array

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

I am trying to display a list of users. The data of users comes from an array. while displaying the list of users, I also want to show different and a random avatar for each of those users.

Here is my code:

```
<q-list>
  <q-item v-for="users in filteredUser">
    <q-item-side :avatar="getRandomAvatar()" />
       <q-item-main class="q-mb-sm" :label="users.first_name + ' ' +  users.last_name "></q-item-main>
    </q-item>
</q-list>
```

function is:

```
getRandomAvatar() {
     this.randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.array_name.length);
     this.temp = array_name[randomNum];
     return this.temp
}
```

So how can I display separate or random avatar for each of the users?

Comment: well you have a function that retrieves a random element from your array already, so you can just do something like `<img :src="getRandomAvatar()" />` right

Comment: We do not know the member of this array you speak of. But whatever you return must be a valid image source, then you can use returned value as `<img :src = "getRandomAvatar()" />`